# Java cucumber: same background in a number of features

Tags: java, cucumber

can i make a "super" feature?
multiple features use the same backgroud steps, can i make them in a different file and run the file instead?

Comment: Are the scenarios using the same steps in a same feature file? Or they are spread across feature files? If the first one then use the "Background" technique.

Comment: second one, thats exactly the question :)

Comment: In that case you should use hook, tag your scenarios and hook appropriately. Alternate is use [QAF-gherkin factory](https://qmetry.github.io/qaf/latest/gherkin_client.html), and create testNG listener.

Answer (score 0):

There is no concept of a "super feature file" where you can mention background steps which you can use in other feature files. In Ruby you can call steps from another scenario but it is not supported in Java.

You can achieve your objective by using the Before hook with a tag. In this before hook method you can write up the reusable code. Remember to add the same tag to the desired scenarios and also to run the test with tag in the cucumberoptions.

Big disadvantage of this is the steps are no longer visible in any feature file. You will have to go into the code to find it out, especially problematic if you have folks not familiar or access to your code who are writing scenarios. Guess you can use it if the background steps are technical setup etc.

Answer (score 0):

Lets say you have a background that you want to share which looks something like

```
Background: 
  Given foo
  And bar
  And baz
  ...
```

They way to share this is to turn it into a naming problem. All we need to do is give the whole background a single name. In this silly example lets use 'wibble'

Now we can just do

```
Background:
  Given wibble
```

And implement that (ideally using helper methods) as

```
Given 'wibble' do
  foo
  bar
  baz
  ...
end
```

In doing this you have discovered something that is important to you domain (wibble). You've also solved your problem, and created something that can be used in more complex backgrounds e.g.

```
Background:
  Given wibble
  And wobble
```

The reason there is no 'super feature' is because there is no need for it :)